helm uninstall, how to delete pods in order?
I have some pods but I don't want to put them in a statefulset.
Is there any way to specify the order in which pods should be deleted when executing helm uninstall?

In Kubernetes, when you uninstall a Helm chart, the resources are deleted according to their dependencies and not in a specific order that you can control directly via Helm or Kubernetes. This is particularly true for pods, which higher-level controllers like Deployments or ReplicaSets generally manage.
However, if you really want to ensure a specific order of deletion, you can use a custom pre-delete hook in your Helm chart to perform cleanup in the desired order before the actual resources are deleted.

...and that will only help so much; if you try deleting Pods before a Deployment that manages them, the Deployment will recreate them.

You cant control the delete order, Helm uninstalls the Resources by a predefined list that you can find here:
https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-2.13/pkg/tiller/kind_sorter.go#L62
